# .htaccess RewriteRule not redirecting to the correct place

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We found hundreds of 404 in one of our blogs, the previous team, deleted a lot of tags and articles. We are trying to create a 301 that redirects anything with /blog/forums in on WP app to WP /knowledge a different WP.

We have many instances like

blog/forums/topic/native-property-window/
blog/forums/user/hemo2/
blog/forums/topic-tag/wql/

We need the redirect to work no matter whats after blog/forums

and redirect them to

/knowledge

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect anything starting with `blog/forums/` to `/knowledge` is pretty simple

```
RewriteRule ^blog/forums/ /knowledge [R,L]
```